# Simple currency conversion function

Tags: python, function, arguments, parameter-passing

I can't figure out why my USD total won't print correctly. All I would like is for the user's input to be multiplied by 0.73 and print usd_total.

I am getting this error:

usd_total = aus_to_us(us_exchange * aud_amount)
TypeError: aus_to_us() missing 1 required positional argument: 'aud'

```
def aus_to_us(exchange_rate, aud):
    usdConversion = exchange_rate * aud
    return usdConversion

aud_amount = float(input('Enter the amount in AUD: '))
us_exchange = 0.73
usd_total = aus_to_us(us_exchange * aud_amount)
print('The amount in USD is: ', usd_total)
```

Comment: Change that asterisk to a comma for function arguments.

Comment: Define *"correctly"* and expand on how that differs from the current outcome.

Comment: In general, you should state what outcome you want, and what "incorrrect" outcome you are getting.  (Errors, etc.)

Comment: I've changed the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `aus_to_us` takes 2 arguments, you need to pass in 2 arguments. Did you mean to put `usd_total = aus_to_us(us_exchange, aus_amount)` ?

Comment: I want the aus_to_us function to have the conversion rate 0.73 x aus_amount passed as a parameter.

Comment: Was that wrong to do that Brian?

Comment: The way you have it set up, it looks like you need to provide the conversion rate (us_exchange) and the amount in Australian dollars (aus_amount). If this is how you want it to be set up, then you need to have both variables passed in as parameters, as shown in my answer. The way you're proposing would not be a functional way to do it, rather it would just be multiplying in your call and returning exactly what you passed in.